# Mac OSX Terminal: Copy Window Contents

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

I am running a java script, which has some text output. I'd like to copy/paste that output. If I do ⌘-A, it copies everything that's been typed that session, even if I typed `clear` beforehand. How can I copy only what is currently displayed?

Comment: Use your mouse to select the text you want to copy and hit `⌘-C` or Right-click then copy.

Comment: It's a lot of text. This would take forever

Comment: "only what is currently displayed?" is almost certainly less than 80 lines. It would take what? Half a second? A *full* second?

Comment: How would you possibly know what my java program outputs? It's about 10,000 lines

Comment: I have no idea what your program outputs but you asked "How can I copy only what is currently displayed?" So… do you want to copy the whole output (use `pbcopy`) or "what's currently displayed" (select then `Cmd+C`)?

Answer (score 2):

- Use [pbcopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html):

> echo 'sup3ru53r' | pbcopy

- Select the text and copy (<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

Comment: What do I put in place of `sup3ru53r`?

Comment: The thing you want to copy. I'm not familiar with java but you need to type the command to run the script instead of the echo sup3ru53r

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying your code, you can...:

- Set the number of buffered lines equal to your screen size, in Terminal Preferences.  It can be found under the Settings tab, and then the Windows button.
- Clear the scrollback buffer with <kbd>cmd-K</kbd> immediately before running your script, then use <kbd>cmd-A C</kbd> as normal.